# Encapsulation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

A long time ago, I saw someone encapsulate their entire JavaScript block with code something like the code below:

```
(function() {
  // ...
})(this);
```

Questions:

1. Is the code above correct?
2. What benefit is there to encapsulating the entire JavaScript block like denoted above?

Comment: I think 'encapsulate' is a misleading term here and should be changed to 'scope' with regard to OOP concepts

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. It's called a self invoking anonymous function expression.

JavaScript variables have either function scope, or global scope. There is no block scope. Enclosing your code in a self invoking function like the one in your example creates a temporary local scope for single-use, immediately-run code, without polluting the global namespace.

Consider the following:

```
<html>
<body>
...
<script>
   (function() { 
      var x = '';

      function myFunction () {
         alert('Hello: ' + x);
      }

      x = 'Bob';
      myFunction();

      alert(typeof x);            // string
      alert(typeof myFunction);   // function
   })();

   alert(typeof x);               // undefined
   alert(typeof myFunction);      // undefined
</script>
<script src="other-javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Whatever you declare in that self invoking function is held in a separate scope. The variable `x` and the function `myFunction()` cannot be accessed from anywhere else. The code in `other-javascript.js` won't see them, for example, and it would be free to declare another function `myFunction()` without conflicts.

Comment: So is "block" scope like a private variable?

Comment: @user434493: Unlike C, C++, Java, and other languages, the variable `y` in `if (x > 5) { var y = 0; }` can be accessed from outside the `if` block... That would have been block scope, but JavaScript variables are stored in a function environment, and are not affected by other `{ }` blocks. Let me update my answer with an example...

Comment: How would you set a variable from outside of the encapsulation to an object from within the encapsulation?

Comment: The preferred term seems to be now ["immediately invoked function expression" (IIFE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression). Probably because it's not invoking itself. (See also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE?retiredLocale=de).)

Answer (score 39):

Also addition to the @Daniel's answer, passing `this` to the function is a common pattern to have a reference to the global object, for example:

```
(function(window){

})(this);
```

In browser scripting the global object has a property named `window` which refers to the global object itself, in other environments there is no `window` property.

Also, another thing that can be done is to specify an argument named `undefined`, because the `undefined` property is not described on the *ECMAScript 3rd*. Edition Standard (there is no guarantee that exist or not), and in some implementations the property is mutable, for example:

```
(function(window, undefined){

})(this);
```

In the above example, we have two *local identifiers* (which are a bit faster to resolve), `window` and `undefined`, only the first one is passed (`this`, which always refers to the global object in *Global code* (code that is outside of any function)), and the second, will contain the primitive [`undefined`](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/) value, because we are not passing any value to it.

That pattern is used by some libraries like [jQuery](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/intro.js#L16).

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, ECMA TC39 had proposed a private syntax. According to the proposal, in order to make a javascript class field private you need to prefix it with a hash '#'. This is to provide some sort of runtime encapsulation.

Example:

```
class B {
  #hidden = 0;
  m() {
    return this.#hidden;
  }
}
```

Chrome supports this since Chrome v74. If this private-syntax becomes a standart we will be able to benefit from runtime encapsulation in javascript and assumingly in typescript since it's transpilation will be updated that way.