# What is (function(x){})(x) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, grammar

I have recently came to know that it is hard to call asynchronous call in for loop. The solution was to use `(function(x){})(x)` to maintain the variable `x` for each asynchronous call. I see this kind of code often, but I can't figure out about how it maintains variable and about its grammar. I would be appreciated if you anyone can explain about this code snippet.

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: it is used to create a local closure if you are talking about something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Comment: @ArunPJohny There's a dup question but couldn't find.

Comment: @C-link: see on the "linked"?

Comment: I marked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-this-iife-construct-in-javascript) as a duplicate.. but then when I read the question again found that it is about closure usage... so even though the principle is the same I'm not sure whether it will answer the question

Comment: @ArunPJohny Your link is very helpful. I found the link on the page you mentioned. http://skilldrick.co.uk/2011/04/closures-explained-with-javascript/ I guess it's something like defining nested function and calling it right away, isn't it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896749/what-does-function-function-window-jquery-do/10896946#10896946

Comment: @jfriend00 this is about dup...

Comment: @sean it is related to a concept called as [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

Comment: Have a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203897/a-self-invoking-anonymous-function-expression