# Should I put my entire Javasscript script inside a self invoking function?

Tags: javascript

I once read that it's good practice to enclose your whole script inside a self invoking function instead of just directly writing it to the document.

eg. Do this:

```
(function ()
{
  //code here

})():
```

Although when I do this, it's more difficult to debug because all variables are outside of scope, and also I can't create objects from external classes. I remember the source saying that this should be done as a security measure. Is this good practice? If so, why?

Comment: It avoids polluting the global scope. You can still debug it by using... well, the debugger. Not sure what you mean about "external classes", the IIFE has access to everything the "bare" code would.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203897/a-self-invoking-anonymous-function-expression

Comment: @DaveNewton I keep my classes inside a separate document. When I try to create an instance of that class in the main script (self-invoked script) it says that the class is undefined.

Comment: @hsbsid unless the classes in the separate document are scoped in a self-invoking anonymous function, that claim doesn't really make sense. The idea is to expose anything that needs to be accessed by other components to the global scope by doing ``window.MyClass = MyClass;`` or something similar inside the self-invoking function.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts should the `window.MyClass = MyClass;` be added to the main script?

Comment: @hsbsid I don't mean that literally, unless you actually have a function called ``MyClass``, but if you want other scripts to be able to access the class outside the self-invoking anonymous function, then yes, you should do that.