# Run something only once, not using .one ()

Tags: jquery

I've code a piece of code that goes like this:

```
$('img').load(function(){
    $(this).doStuff(); // here could be one, two, or more images
    doSomethingElse(); // I want this part to run only ONCE
});
function doSomethingElse(){
    // code here unfortunately runs one, two, or more times (depending on how many imgs there are)
}
```

I'm not sure how to apply jQuery `.one()` in this situation. I've tried searching online for a way to run something only once, but all I ever seem to find are recommendations to try using jQuery `.one()`.

There must be some way to run `doSomethingElse` only once, even if multiple images are loaded. I suppose I could use a `setTimeout` and wait for all the images to have loaded, but I would be guessing how long this takes so that solution seems a bit weak.

Comment: You can look into [Self Invoking Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203897/a-self-invoking-anonymous-function-expression). Basic syntax: `(function(){})()`. These function will execute only once when file is loaded.

Comment: try this `$('img').load(function(){
    $(this).doStuff(); // here could be one, two, or more images
    doSomethingElse(); // I want this part to run only ONCE

return; // make it run only once
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this using a simple boolean flag:

```
var done = false;

$('img').load(function(){
    $(this).doStuff(); // here could be one, two, or more images

    if (!done)
    {
        done = true;
        doSomethingElse(); // I want this part to run only ONCE
    }
});

function doSomethingElse(){
    // code here unfortunately runs one, two, or more times (depending on how many imgs there are)
}
```

This way, you set your `done` variable the first time the load function runs, and each time it runs thereafter, it skips the call to `doSomethingElse()`.