# Event Listener fires multiple times and on all activated objects

Tags: javascript

My code is as follows with a nested EventListener:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <div>Message: <input id="box" /></div>
                        <button id="okay">Okay</button>
<form>
     <div id="rows">
         <div>Row 1: <input class="row" id="rowtext[0]" name="row[0]" readonly> <button type="button" id="input[0]" class="activate_row">Activate Row</button></div>
     <div>Row 2: <input class="row" id="rowtext[1]" name="row[1]" readonly> <button type="button" id="input[1]" class="activate_row">Activate Row</button></div>
     <div>Row 3: <input class="row" id="rowtext[2]" name="row[2]" readonly> <button type="button" id="input[2]" class="activate_row">Activate Row</button></div>
     <div>Row 4: <input class="row" id="rowtext[3]" name="row[3]" readonly> <button type="button" id="input[3]" class="activate_row">Activate Row</button></div>
     <div>Row 5: <input class="row" id="rowtext[4]" name="row[4]" readonly> <button type="button" id="input[4]" class="activate_row">Activate Row</button></div>
  </div>
 <div>
    Activated Row (for debugging): <input id="activated" name="activated">
 </div>

</form>
<script>
   var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
   var  activatebuttons= document.getElementsByClassName("activate_row");
   for (var i = 0; i < activatebuttons.length; i++){
       activatebuttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
          var idnum = this.id.slice(6,-1);
          var box = document.getElementById("box")
          var rowText = document.getElementById("rowtext[" + idnum + "]");

          document.getElementById("activated").value = idnum;
          box.value = rowText.value;
          document.getElementById("okay").addEventListener('click', function(){
             alert("ID (for debugging): " + idnum);
             rowText.value = box.value;
          });
      });
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Click on a "Activate Row" button to activate a particular row.
2. Type a message in the Message box
3. Press Okay
4. The message should get copied to the appropriate row

This works fine the first time. However, each time I click on one of the "Activate Row" buttons, whether it is the same one or a different one, it seems to add an additional event listener to the "Okay" button. This can be seen with the "alert" I used for debugging.

**The problem is that my message gets copied to every row that had previously been activated rather than only the currently activated row. Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?**

To clarify: What I want to happen is for the message to only get copied to the row that was activated. Not to all rows that had previously been activated.

Comment: Because that what you do :).  You are adding an event listener to "okay" in your activatebutton click event. To fix it, move okay event listener out side for loop.

Comment: If I move it outside of the for loop I will no longer have access to the idnum.

Comment: You do, use document.getElementById("activated").value as idnum

Comment: Sorry, that was just for debugging purposes. I do not really want the id num to be displayed at all.

Comment: Declare var activated outside for loop and assign idnum to activated variable.

Comment: Okay, thank you. That works. I thought there might be a way without using a global variable though.

Comment: Use encapsulation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597087/encapsulation-in-javascript