# Include and run javascript file in chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, developer-tools

Extending this question : [Include javascript file in chrome console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282228/include-javascript-file-in-chrome-console)

I'm trying to include this file : https://rawgit.com/mapbox/tokml/master/tokml.js

Tried using the example above, and several other following the same principle, but whenever I call `tokml` in console it always gives `is not defined`

I think it has something to do with it being encapsulated in a function? It is a bundled node.js module, I wouldn't know how to edit it so that it is no longer encapsulated.

How can I call `toklm` from my cdn in a website?

It also doesn't need to be in chrome, open to all alternatives

Comment: Yes, I believe its encapsulated therefore you cant access it from there. I'm not familiar as to how that js works and if it stores any values that it returns but you cant access anything from there directly.

Comment: All I know is that it works when I put in a script tag, but not through this method.

Comment: You are including it from the console to the page not to the console. You can't access the functions from the included file through the console nor that page if its inside `(function(){ //code })();`.
Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3597102/6586663) out.

Comment: And the solution? ^^

Comment: Well, what is that file that you are including? Do you only need it to do its job and not interact with it directly? Either way I think I answered your problem. I don't know what you need or what you are working on.

Comment: That file is the "tokml" function that I need to call from console, that's it

Comment: If [this](https://github.com/mapbox/tokml) is what you are using then i recommend reading the API and documentation with an [example](https://github.com/mapbox/tokml#example) of how to call and use it on that official github page.

Answer (score 0):

### Example

```
// kml is a string of KML data, geojsonObject is a JavaScript object of
// GeoJSON data
var kml = tokml(geojsonObject);

// grab name and description properties from each object and write them in
// KML
var kmlNameDescription = tokml(geojsonObject, {
    name: 'name',
    description: 'description'
});

// name and describe the KML document as a whole
var kmlDocumentName = tokml(geojsonObject, {
    documentName: 'My List Of Markers',
    documentDescription: "One of the many places you are not I am"
});
```

### API

#### `tokml(geojsonObject, [options])`

Given [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) data as an object, return KML data as a
string of XML.

`options` is an optional object that takes the following options:

**The property to name/description mapping:** while GeoJSON supports freeform
`properties` on each feature, KML has an expectation of `name` and `description`
properties that are often styled and displayed automatically. These options let
you define a mapping from the GeoJSON style to KML's.

- `name`: the name of the property in each GeoJSON Feature that contains
  the feature's name
- `description`: the name of the property in each GeoJSON Feature that contains
  the feature's description

**Timestamp:** KML can associate features with a moment in time via the `TimeStamp` tag.  GeoJSON doesn't
have a comparable field, but a custom property can be mapped

- `timestamp`: the name of the property in each GeoJSON Feature that contains 
  a timestamp in XML Schema Time (yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:sszzzzzz)

**Document name and description**: KML supports `name` and `description` properties
for the full document.

- `documentName`: the name of the full document
- `documentDescription`: the description of the full document

**[simplestyle-spec](https://github.com/mapbox/simplestyle-spec)** support:

- `simplestyle`: set to `true` to convert simplestyle-spec styles into KML styles

**Source: https://github.com/mapbox/tokml#example**